# How can I get a Netgear GS748Tv1 bootloader?

Tags: netgear, boot-loader

We own a Netgear GS748Tv1 (serial 141*). Sadly, due to a firmware update gone wrong, the bootloader got flashed away into oblivion.

Since the warranty is expired, Netgear will not help us (this comes from their support staff). The firmware on their support site does not seem to include a bootloader.

We would like to avoid replacing the hardware since we are a non-profit and cannot really afford it now.

Can you help me find a suitable bootloader? A full image of a similar but still working device's flash memory would be just as good.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it is any help to you, but I found an old page with Beta firmware you may be able to try?

<strike>http://kbserver.netgear.com/release_notes/d102705.asp</strike>

<strike>http://kb.netgear.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/13184 <- Or this one?</strike>

Maybe worth checking out. Another option might be to see if you can contact someone that has one listed on ebay. They may be able to get you the file at a small cost, it beats buying another one!

Comment: Thanks, I'll see if that firmware contains the bootloader. I haven't tried asking on ebay yet, will see if that works.

Comment: Well, sadly this firmware doesn't seem to have the bootloader either.

Comment: There is a boot loader in this download, not sure if it will suit your switch? http://kb.netgear.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/13184

Comment: Initially we discarded this download as fitting a very different switch, but now that the actual bootloader is so elusive, we may give it a whirl. Will report back once we have some results:)

Comment: My friend took a look at that code and claims it isn't compatible either. We also took a look inside a GS724T switch and found that it unfortunately has entirely different hardware inside.

Comment: No worries. I will let you know if I come across anything else ;)

Comment: Maybe have a look around her: ftp://downloads.netgear.com/files/ I couldn't find it but it may be hidden in a sub directory or have an obscure name.